# Implementing Regex in phpmailer script to prevent spamming

Tags: php, regex, input, phpmailer, spam-prevention

I'm a web designer and I don't know how php works.
The website I'm working on, is on a smtp server and the form needed host address, username and password to send emails, so I found and modified this script for my use.

Here is my problem:
I need to use Regex on the script down below to prevent spam; as I said I don't know php at all and everything I tried went wrong.

Would you please help me? Thanks :)

```
<?php

require("class.phpmailer.php");





$name = $_POST["firstName"];

$email = $_POST["email"];

$object = $_POST["oggetto"];

$message = $_POST["message"];



$nomemittente = $name . ' ' . $email;





$messaggio = "<div style=\"font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;\"><br>

<strong>Nome:</strong> " . $name . "<br>

<strong>Object:</strong> " . $object . "<br>

<strong>E-mail:</strong> " . $email . "<br><br>

<strong>Testo:</strong> "  . $testo . "<br><br>

</div>";



$mail = new PHPMailer();



$mail->IsSMTP(); 

// L'host remoto con cui spediremo, nel caso di gmail è smtp.gmail.com

$mail->Host = "xxx.xxxx.it";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;



// Specifichiamo che vogliamo spedire tramite ssl, se non volete basta eliminae queste due righe

/*$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->Port = 465;
*/



$mail->Username = "xxxxxxxxx";

$mail->Password = "xxxxx";


$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;



$mail->From = "$email";

$mail->FromName = "$name";



// Qui inseriamo l'indirizzo a cui recapitare le email spedite tramite il form

$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxxxx@xx.com");



$mail->AddReplyTo("$email", "$nome");





$mail->WordWrap = 50; 



$mail->IsHTML(true);



$mail->Subject = "$nomemittente - Requested informations";

$mail->Body    = "$messaggio</b>";



    if($mail->Send()){

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Message sent!')</script>";
    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'index.html';\",400);</script>"; 

    }else{


        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Something goes wrong!)</script>";
    echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'index.html';\",400);</script>";
    } 


?>
```

Comment: What should that regex do?

Comment: phpmailer sends emails, so are you protecting against yourself? Not sure what you mean by *preventing spam*

Comment: Is `$nome` an error, or maybe you just translated and forget that?

Comment: @ctwheels I don't want that bots or spam programs send email using the form

Comment: @NicoHaaseRegex must check if: $name is only alphabetical and if so, letting phpmailer send the email. $email is a valid address and if so, letting phpmailer send email.

Comment: Probably best to add a captcha.

Comment: @LeonardChallis $nome is the original language, I forgot to translate in english ;)

Comment: @Synchro I found something about it but I don't know how to implement it with phpmailer :-(

Comment: @Blizzard983 just look at Google's [ReCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/android.html)

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with PHPMailer - it sits in front of it, so if they don't pass the captcha test, no PHPMailer-related code is run at all.

Comment: @ctwheels Ok I'll take a look and I'll let u know. Thx :)

Comment: @Synchro got it, I'll give it a try :)